# order data and show by date

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}                
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
   public List<Person> Persons {get; set; }

   public MyDate()
   {
      Persons = new List<Person>();
   }           
}
```

I want to display persons ordered by date like

date entered in day 28.05.2015

```
Name1
Name2
```

date entered in day 27.05.2015

```
Name
```

date entered in day 26.05.2015

```
Name
```

Comment: Why are you asking the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503167/display-data-sorted-by-date

Comment: Ok, great. You have our permission to do so. If you encounter problems doing it, feel free to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyData data = new MyData();

// 
// input data ...
// 

// iteration    
foreach (var group in from e in data.Persons
                      group e by e.Created.Date into g
                      select g)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Data entered in day {0}", group.Key.ToShortDateString());
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}
```